# adding a "closed due to duplicate on main/other meta/site" option/notice

Tags: discussion, migration

Quite recently I was asked on a meta site to post my original question from there onto the main meta instead, as it would be of StackExchange-wide scope. I then followed the moderator's advice, and then later another moderator closed the original with the notice "closed as off-topic".

That felt a little weird psychologically. Would it be possible to offer an option/notice "closed due to duplicate on main/other meta/site" or "closed due to requested migration" or some such? Even if "direct" migration is the desired mechanism (and preferred over reposting with deletion of the original), it might sound more positive/motivating/encouraging to beginners. (And, additional mechanisms such as what I'm proposing can never hurt, even if they're technically superfluous - in this case, because the user should (very much arguably) not have posted on the site meta in the first place.)

(I know there are similar questions here, but I think this specific issue merits some attention. Do correct me if I'm wrong.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would much prefer folks didn't close posts on per-site metas in deference to those on other sites. Even when a particular suggestion is applicable network-wide, it may have advantages or provoke concerns specific to an individual site.

We have these things called "hyperlinks" that can be used to link posts across sites - to create one, just post the URL of one question into the other, and submit. Do this for both, and you've now cross-linked the suggestions. Separate discussions can continue without being missed by either community.

Comment: Hyperlinks?  What foul magick is this?

Comment: @Shog9 Creating hyperlinks - that's what I've done. In fact, the first suggestion by an experienced user to me was to post on the main meta instead. I simply followed that suggestion, trusting the (much more experienced user) and adding a link (yep). The other user then told me to please not double-post and that he'd "closed as off-topic" my original question. I thought this was a bit rude-ish, since I thought I had done the right thing. So we probably need some policy to prevent newbies (like me) from getting into that situation, or at least from us feeling better about it.

Comment: @Shog9 Incidentally, both were site moderators, and so basically one moderator told me off for following the other moderator's suggestion. All this wasn't overtly impolite, but the situation was somewhat off-putting for a beginner.

Comment: @user14996: in [this particular case](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2550/renaming-of-strunk-white-badge), I suspect the moderators were trying to be helpful but it did come across a bit rough. FWIW, you could've simply deleted your original question yourself after re-posting here, since there didn't seem to be much interest in it on tex.se.

Comment: @Shog9 Really no big deal at all. But I was bringing it up here because I love to improve things (in this case by drawing attention to a situation where a beginner was initially unaware of the main meta and also the cross-existence of a certain badge). I'm not sure whether there *is* something to improve infrastructurally or in terms of moderation policy/advice, but if anyone would know it'd be someone here :-)